# Passing arrays between methods, and accessing them accordingly

Tags: arrays, methods

I'm supposed to use two methods to hold arrays, then with the two arrays determine win % of the rockets, average margin of score difference for the games lost by Houston Rockets, and the lowest Houston Rockets’ score and the corresponding game number. I primarily need help with the first one, and I can get the other tasks. I just dont know how to pass arrays from methods very well. Any help would be useful, THanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MorenoJonathonRocketsStatistics
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 System.out.println("enter rockets game scores");
 int[] rockets = rocketsScore();
 System.out.println("enter opponents scores");
 int[] opponents = opponentsScore();
  int per = percent();
 System.out.println("game win percent"+per+" %");

}

public static int[] rocketsScore()
 {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int[] rocketsScore = new int[8];

 for(int i=0;i<rocketsScore.length;i++)
 {
 rocketsScore[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
 return rocketsScore;
}

 public static int[] opponentsScore()
 {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int[] opponentsScore = new int[8];

 for(int i=0;i<opponentsScore.length;i++)
  {
   opponentsScore[i] = sc.nextInt();
  }
return opponentsScore;

 }

 public static int percent(int[] array, int[] array2)
 {
  int[] rock = rocketsScore.length();
  int[] opp = opponentsScore.length();
  double percent=0;
  int w=0, l=0;
  for(int i=0; i<rocketsScore.length;i++)
   {
   if(rocketsScore[i]>opponentsScore[i])
  {
   w++;
   }
   else{
    l++;
   }
 }
 percent = w/l;
 return percent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass array in methods, you don't need to put any brackets beside the variable that is holding the array. So, you may want to do it like below:

```
int per = percent(rockets, opponents);
```